# Django: Unknown column error when running on production server

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

When I try to access my Django application on the production server (AWS EBS), it keeps returning the following error `(1054, "Unknown column 'two_factor_phonedevice.throttling_failure_timestamp' in 'field list'")`.

Strangely, the app works fine when running locally using the exact same MYSQL database (AWS RDS) and settings.
I have tried dropping the database and re-running migrations believing it was due to an inconsistency between my db and migrations files however I still keep getting the same error.

I am using the `django_two_authentication` module for the user authentication/logins. The table `two_factor_phonedevice` is created by the module to track the user devices registered for two factor authentication.

I cannot seem to solve why the column can be found when running locally but cannot be found on the production server despite both using the same database.

Comment: Looks like you are using different versions of the package locally and in production. Check the versions in `pip list` in both environments.

Comment: This was indeed the problem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the module version was not specified in the production requirements.txt file meaning the newest version (which happened to have a different db schema) was installed by default causing different versions to be running locally and in production environments.

To resolve this I explicitly set the module version in the requirements.txt file to match that of the local one.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `django_two_authentication` specifically, but I would check the different settings module you are using in each environment.
You may have differences in the `INSTALLED_APPS` or some other relevant entry.

Comment: I have used the same settings for both local and production server but still encounter the error..